# Installed TOR but can't locate browser

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, tor

So I've installed TOR, via the directions [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
deb.torproject.org-keyring is already the newest version.
tor is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 109 not to upgrade.
```

But I can not locate my tor browser in apps?

Comment: Can you open a Terminal and run `tor` or `tor-browser`? Does it work that way?

Comment: You downloaded the Tor daemon. The browser is currently not available as official package. If you want to use it, you need to download it from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

After I followed the instructions from the [aforementioned](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) guide. I downloaded the Tor-Browser from [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).

I then extracted the contents and ran the ***.desktopfile*** from within that folder. Everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just call it from terminal with `torbrowser`

If it works, you can [create a *.desktop* file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

---

Anyway, you can configure your system in system > network > mandatory > *manually* and set

socks host to *localhost* on the port *9050*

Then, all your application (those set on system default) will transit by the tor network.

Hope it helps.